# C # Compare 2 lists of ints of different size

Tags: c#, list, comparison

I currently have 2 lists that I want to compare which will never have equal length.

`List<int> data` which is of n length

`List<int> numbersToSeekFor` which is of n length and contains the set of all distinct values in `data`

`List<Color> colorsToAssign` whose length is the same as `numbersToSeekFor`

What I want to achieve, and not been very successful, is to compare all the items in `data` to each index of `numbersToSeekFor`. If this condition is true the first `index` of `colorsToAssign`will be added to a list and then the second index and so forth...

A very dumb example of the following would be this method. Were I am assuming that there are 3 elements in `numbersToSeekFor`. The output list of this method should also be of equal size as `data`.

```
public List<Color> Foo(List<int> data, List<int>numbersToSeekFor, List<Color> colorsToAssign)
  {
    List<Color> colors = new List<Color>();
    for (int i = 0; i < data.Count; i++)
    {



        if(data[i] == numbersToSeekFor[0])
        {
          colors.Add(colorsToAssign[0]);

        }

        if(data[i] == numbersToSeekFor[1] )
        {
          colors.Add(colorsToAssign[1]);


        }

        if(data[i] == numbersToSeekFor[2])
        {
          colors.Add(colorsToAssign[2]);


        }


    }

    return colors;
  }
```

What would be the cleanest way to achieve this?

Thank you for your help

Comment: It seems also to be contradictory to say on the one hand `which will never have equal length`, but then `List<int> data which is of n length` and `List<int> numbersToSeekFor which is of n length`, so both seem to have the same length n?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you could use a comination of LINQ `.Where` and `.Select` methods:

```
public static List<Color> Foo3(List<int> data, List<int> numbersToSeekFor, List<Color> colorsToAssign)
{
    if (data?.Any() != true || numbersToSeekFor?.Any() != true || colorsToAssign?.Count != data.Count)
    {
        return new List<Color>();
    }

    List<Color> colors = data
                         .Select(d => numbersToSeekFor.IndexOf(d))
                         .Where(i => i > -1 && i < colorsToAssign.Count)
                         .Select(i => colorsToAssign[i])
                         .ToList();
    return colors;
}
```

Comment: Fabjan thanks for your reply. Sorry that I did not clearify this in the post, but the length of colors has to be the same as data. At the moment with your example colors only has 2 elements. and I believe its because of the    i<colorsToAssign.Count and i<numbersToSeekFor.Count conditions

Comment: @Nicholas I've changed the code according to your needs. At first I thought we're comparing values strictly by indexes...

Answer (score 1):

If I understand it correctly, numbersToSeekFor is meant for mapping a number in data to an index in colorsToAssign. So maybe it would be a good idea to convert to to a Dictionary first:

```
var mapNumberToIndex = new Dictionary<int, int>();
for (var i = 0; i < numbersToSeekFor.Count; i++)
    mapNumberToIndex.Add(numbersToSeekFor[i], i);
```

Then you could simple use

```
colors.Add(mapNumberToIndex[data[i]]);
```

in your loop

Answer (score 0):

You could use a dictionary to map values onto colours, and do away with the need to pass in a separate list of all the distinct values:

```
    public static List<Color> AssignColours(List<int> data, List<Color> coloursToAssign)
    {
        var result = new List<Color>();
        var map    = new Dictionary<int, Color>();
        int n      = 0;

        foreach (var datum in data)
        {
            if (!map.TryGetValue(datum, out var colour))
            {
                // Next line will throw exception if number of distinct numbers
                // is greater than length of coloursToAssign.

                colour = coloursToAssign[n++];
                map[datum] = colour;
            }

            result.Add(colour);
        }

        return result;
    }
```

This code assumes that the count of distinct values is <= the length of `coloursToAssign`, otherwise there will be an exception at the commented line.

Alternatively (and more efficiently if you're calling this several times) you can precalculate the map like so:

```
public static Dictionary<int, Color> MapColours(List<int> numbersToSeekFor, List<Color> coloursToAssign)
{
    var map = new Dictionary<int, Color>();

    for (int i = 0; i < numbersToSeekFor.Count; ++i)
        map[numbersToSeekFor[i]] = coloursToAssign[i];

    return map;
}
```

and then use it like so:

```
var map = MapColours(numbersToSeekFor, coloursToAssign);

...

var colourToUse = map[data[someIndex]];
```